# Create an unbreakable ideal image/snapshot of an operating system, save that to the external hard disk, and load an operating system from that disk

Tags: windows

I am technical maintainer of 60 computers.

The purpose: I want to have the computers that are not volunerable from naive actions of users and virures.

Implementation: to have an operating system loaded from an image(here, image does not refer to some specific file image format, it's just an abstraction).

So every time when the operating system (for example windows) will be loaded the content of OS , installed programs, everything will be load from the saved image.

Again, the question is not about how to install windows to 60 computers, the question is how to make the single image and then load operating system from it on 60 computers.

Of course I wanna to be able to modify the image, if I disliked some installed program, I can uninstall that from image. So there will be some kind of audit mode. After entering to audit mode I can do changes, then save the image. And next time it will load the new image.

Again, if you want to suggest acronis true image, then, probably you haven't understand the question. as I know,acronis true image is only for fast system cloning .

Also the image should be stored in some unmarked(no letter) parition which is not seen from windows or ubuntu.

It will be good if the image can load grub, and then using grub I can load Windows or Linux.
So the image will be kinda virtualization of hard disk.

Edit: Additonally, it will be good to make loading an OS from central server using network.

Thanks,
Nusrat

Comment: Does it have to be windows ?

Comment: Windows is mandatory. Windows + Ubuntu is optional.

Comment: Are you saying you want the computer to boot from an image that cannot be modified by the end-users each time they start the machine? Or are you wanting to create an image for deployment?

Comment: Does it need to be for physical PCs, or can it be a VM-centric solution?

Comment: @Raystafarian First one, an image that cannot be modified by the end users each time they start machine. However, an easy deployment of unmodifyable image is an additional great bonus.

Comment: Then why not create a virtual environment for your users? Whether it's connecting to a virtual server or making them run a virtual machine? That seems to be what you want.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, it need to be for physical PCs. Also the physical mahcines are almost have same hardware configuration. What is Virtual Machine-centric solution? what do you mean?

Comment: I suppose that answers @Raystafarian's question, too.

Comment: @Raystafarian What is a virtual environment? Could you provide conrete examples? What is the complexity of virtual environment implementation? And the most important what is the speed of virtual environment (Computers have only 2gigs of ram and 2.6 Ghz of Core2)? Is virtual environment good, if the en-users are developers, students?

Comment: [I'd start here with desktop virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg176676%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your description looks like Windows 7 SteadyState solution: http://blogs.technet.com/b/panosm/archive/2011/07/07/windows-7-steadystate-solution-simplified.aspx